# Display post count for a specific month

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, date

I am trying to display post count for a specific month, But something is wrong with my query because count is wrong. here I want to get post count for Aprel month. Can anyone help me please ? Thanks for your attention

```
$aprel = get_queried_object();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
$aprelpost = array(
 'post_type' => 'MYCPT',
 'post_status'=>'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
            'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => $aprel->slug,
        ),
        
        'date_query' => array(
        'year'  => 2021,
        'month' => aprel
    )
   )
);
$aprelpost_query = new WP_Query ( $aprelpost );


$ap = $aprelpost_query ->post_count ;
echo ($ap);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is correct answer if someone need

```
$aprel = get_queried_object();

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
$aprelpost = array(
 'post_type' => 'sikayet',
 'post_status'=>'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
            'field'    => 'slug',
           'terms'    => $aprel->slug,
        ),  
   ),
      'date_query' => array(
        'year'  => 2021,
        'month' => 3
    )
);
$aprelpost_query = new WP_Query ( $aprelpost );


$ap = $aprelpost_query ->post_count ;
echo ($ap);
```